# Remove rows when column values already present as an element of a list in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove the rows entirely when the column values of a specific column like `user` is already present as an element of a list in another column. How can I best accommpish this?

```
    user          friend
0   jack         [mary, jane, alex]
1   mary         [kate, andrew, jensen]
2   alice        [marina, catherine, howard]
3   andrew       [syp, yuslina, john ] 
4   catherine    [yute, kelvin]
5   john         [beyond, holand]
```

Expected Output:

```
    user                       friend
0   jack           [mary, jane, alex]
2  alice  [marina, catherine, howard]
```

Comment: is the prior list always a reference?

Comment: There is something non logical, either you only car about the row just above and john should not be removed, or you care about all prior rows and andrew should be removed (present in friends in row 1)

Comment: Thanks @mozway. That's a good catch. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example seems incorrect, as either john should be kept  (blacklist is made of all previous friends), or andrew should be removed (blacklist is only the previous list of friends).

Here are different options.

**Remove is the used is present in:**

#### any set of friends

```
S = set().union(*df['friend'])

mask = ~df['user'].isin(S)
# [False, True, False, True, True, True]

df[mask]
```

output:

```
    user                       friend
0   jack           [mary, jane, alex]
2  alice  [marina, catherine, howard]
```

#### all previous sets of friends

You can first compute an expanding set of friends, then check whether each user is in the set:

```
S = set()
# line below uses python ≥ 3.8, if older version use a classical loop
sets = [(S:=S.union(set(x))) for x in df['friend']]

mask = [u not in s for u,s in zip(df['user'], sets)]
# [True, False, True, False, False, False]
out = df[mask]
```

output:

```
    user                       friend
0   jack           [mary, jane, alex]
2  alice  [marina, catherine, howard]
```

#### only previous set of friends

```
mask = [u not in s for u,s in zip(df['user'], df['friend'].agg(set).shift(fill_value={}))]
# [True, False, True, True, True, True]

out = df[mask]
```

output:

```
        user                       friend
0       jack           [mary, jane, alex]
2      alice  [marina, catherine, howard]
3     andrew         [syp, yuslina, john]
4  catherine               [yute, kelvin]
5       john             [beyond, holand]
```

used input:

```
d = {'user': ['jack', 'mary', 'alice', 'andrew', 'catherine', 'john'],
     'friend': [['mary', 'jane', 'alex'], 
                ['kate', 'andrew', 'jensen'],
                ['marina', 'catherine', 'howard'],
                ['syp', 'yuslina', 'john'],
                ['yute', 'kelvin'],
                ['beyond', 'holand']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the desired column to one list without any nested list. For this purpose you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) then you can use [`pandas.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

*(`andrew` exists in the `[kate, andrew, jensen]` so this solution don't show this row too.)*

```
import itertools
df = df[~df['user'].isin(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['friend'])))]
```

Output:

```
    user                       friend
0   jack           [mary, jane, alex]
2  alice  [marina, catherine, howard]
```